# How to ask user to Play Again....Guess Game

Tags: java

I'm making a simple guess game but I don't know how to ask the player if the want to play the game again.Everytime the game ends I have to run the game again so I want to add this feature to it.I looked in some other posts but they didn't help.Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class guessNumber{
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public guessNumber(){
    System.out.println("~~~Guess Game~~~");
}
public void guessGame(){
System.out.println("Enter the maximum number:");
int maxNum = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and " + maxNum + ":");
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * maxNum);
    boolean gameOn = true;
    int numberOfTries = 0;
    while(gameOn){
    boolean printOthers = true;
    numberOfTries++;
    int number = userInput.nextInt();
    if(number > maxNum){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and " + maxNum + ".");
        printOthers = false;
        }
    if(printOthers){
    if(number == randomNumber){
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("You guessed the right number xD.");
        System.out.println("Your tried " + numberOfTries + " times.");
        System.out.println("=================================");
    }else if(number > randomNumber){
        System.out.println("Try a lower number");
    }else if(number < randomNumber){
        System.out.println("Try a higher number");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and " + maxNum + ".");
    }
    }
}

}
    public static void main(String[] args){
    guessNumber guess = new guessNumber();
    guess.guessGame();




}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main use a while loop. In the loop first call your guessGame() then, similarly to how you ask to enter a number, you ask if they want to play again (Y/N ?) and if they say no you break the loop otherwise you go ahead...

Answer (score 1):

Add your calling method in main method with in a while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
//call your game
System.out.println("Do you want to play again. Press y");
}
while(scanner.next().equals("y"));
```